# Do all USB-C ports support DisplayPort?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, displayport, usb-c

I have a HP ProBook 430 G4 laptop computer. It has USB-C, HDMI and VGA connectors. I would like to connect two monitors, but I just don't like the picture quality of VGA. So I would like to connect the two monitors via USB-C - DisplayPort adapter and HDMI.

However, I am uncertain whether the USB-C connector on this device supports DisplayPort. Do all USB-C connectors support DisplayPort? If not, how about the USB-C connector on this particular device?

QuickSpecs don't offer much information about this: http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c05254141.pdf?ver=7.0

Whenever I connect an ordinary USB-C to 4xUSB 3.0 + USB-C (for daisy chaining) hub, I get this message:

[image: Display connection might be limited]

... so I assume the answer could be negative. What's strange in this message is that the USB-C to 4xUSB 3.0 + USB-C hub does not have a DisplayPort connector!

Comment: It's entirely possible that hub is a universal docking IC with the DisplayPort output unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know will not work thru a hub.

I had same problem, with a Macbook Pro and i bought this:

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/ORICO-DHU3B-BK-USB3-0-to-DVI-HDMI-External-Graphics-for-6-Computer-Screen-Extention-Black/105327_2036412700.html

USB 3.0 adapter to video, supports simultaneous DVI/HDMI. I remember that had same adapter for usb-c, but i couldnt find it now. Maybe another brand you can find it.

Depending of what you will do, should work. For me, worked great.